# SQL Merge Replication between SQL Server 2012 and SQL Server CE, 3.5, sp2

Tags: sql-server-ce, sql-server-2012, merge-replication

Receiving "OpenDB failed getting pub version 28627" in `SQLCESALOG.txt` when trying to create a subscription on SQL Server CE 3.5 sp2.

`server1` is running Win 2008, IIS 7.0, SQL Server CE 3.5 sp2, Replication tools, client tools. This server also hosts the snapshot share. The merge client diag page (http://server1.localhost/websync/sqlcesa35.dll?diag) all checks out except for "9.0 Database Reconciler", which I assumed was not necessary as I am not using SQL Server 2005 (please correct if wrong). The web sync wizard (`connwiz.exe`) set the `/websync` vdir with integrated authentication - every other type is disabled.

`server2` is running Windows 7, SQL Server 2012.

I am using TCP/IP as the client and server protocol. I have tried using the SA account as well as the user account (which i'm using as the service account on each server (is also admin). Nothing seems to work. I don't see a login attempt on the SQL 2012 server. Firewalls are off. I ran netmon and could see port 1433 traffic between the two machines. I have read ErikEJ's blog through and through but nothing there helps me with this error. The only other person I found who had a solution to this resolved it by creating an alias named pipe client protocol. This didn't help me.

The error I see in the log in the websync directory is above. The error the GUI actually presents me with is:

> *Failure to connect to SQL Server with provided information. SQL Server does not exist, access is denied because the SQL user is not a valid user on the SQL server, or the password is incorrect. HRESULT 0x800040005 (29060)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed. I had 2 issues:

1. I was not using the version of SQL CE, SP2 that is supported by SQL 2012 (Cumulative update 7).
2. I did not have the SQL 2012 Replication components installed. I had SQL 2008 R2 replication components installed.

Once I fixed all this, replication started working. However, I lost the ability to use SQL Management Studio to manage my CE database. I now have to use the SQL Server Compact Toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently seen this error, it was caused by wrong SqlCeReplication parameters (specifically, the database name (PublisherDatabase)was wrong. I used the SQL Server Profiler to capture the parameters in the logon attempt.

Comment: I just realized that I am not using cumulative update 6 (or 7) so, I'm guessing this may be (or partly be) the issue connecting to Denali. Just did the re-install but now I am facing another problem - my SQL 2008R2 mgmt tool is not seeing the SQL CE install so I can't manage the db. Now i'm trying to load your toolbox to see if that helps.

Comment: Also, I think I may need to load the SQL 2012 replication tools on the IIS box. I only had 2008R2